# New to Adobe Animate. Trying to make a frame by frame explosion. Need help

Tags: svg, animation, adobe-animate

I'm new to Adobe Animate and animation software but I'm having trouble figuring out where to start.

I want to make a simple explosion, and have created svg files of the individual frames. I want to create a tween in between each frame, but I do not know how to do this.

I can do basic Tweens, but I don't know how to implement what I am trying to do. I know this sounds incredibly vague but I would really appreciate help. Does anybody have any tips on how to do this?

Here is an image of all of my frames

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5NU0.png]

Comment: In my opinion, this kind of explosions should not use an "Inbetween" aproach.

Comment: I should preface this with: I've never done animation like this... buuuut... I think it might be kinda hard to automatically tween that so that it looks good. Might be better just to stick with frame by frame animation with that.

Answer (score 1):

You have sketched 7 keyframes: each of the separate visual elements of the last five keyframes you've sketched would need to be separate items, and would be scaled and colour shifted between keys - tweening would get you the transitions between those keys, but you will need to actually create all these elements in Animate, and... well, animate them... for them to end up animated!

The elements in your first two frames are two concatenated "boom stars", which primarily change through scale; starting at keyframe three, all the elements should be separate but overlapping, to allow them to easily separate and scale independently in all the subsequent keyframes.

My point is that this is not a simple "import keys and tween" workflow: you need to actually do the work to animate this, no matter what software suite you're using.